# Can't connect to Mongodb running on EC2

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I cannot connect remotely to a mongo server running on EC2, even though if I ssh into the server the mongo is running properly. Also note, that the `27017` port is open on both tcp and udp protocols. I am getting the following error:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: ec2-x...x-compute.amazonaws.com:27017/test
Thu Sep  4 13:26:04.293 Error: couldn't connect to server to: ec2-x...x-compute.amazonaws.com:27017/test at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:147
exception: connect failed
```

I have `Mongodb version 2.4.8` on my local host and on the server `Mongodb version 2.6.4`. Could the version difference be a problem?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Are you binding to the external IP? Or just localhost:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

```
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1 # Should be 0.0.0.0 to listen on all interfaces
  port: 27017
```

Also, I know you said that the port is open. Did you check this using nmap/netcat? You should check the AWS security group and the local firewall to make sure it's open.

Comment: I had the right permissions, but `mongod` was listening only on localhost and the port was disabled as well. After setting the `bingIp` and `port` everything worked. Thanks!

Comment: remember to restart the mongod service if installed like that with `sudo service mongod restart` :)

Comment: you can also bind multiple Ip adrress
bindIp = [127.0.0.1, 192.168.184.155, 96.88.169.145]